# want to fetch data from database table.... what should i do

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table. It looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE joke
(sn INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
, jokes VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

There are currently five rows in the table.

In my webpage there are 5 textareas. I want to fetch each joke to a textarea.

I have done it by this way, but I think it is not a good way. Are there other ways?

```
<?php
$sql=myql_query(SELECT jokes FROM tbl_jk WHERE sn=1;)
?>
<?php
$sql1=myql_query(SELECT jokes FROM tbl_jk WHERE sn=2;)
?>
<textarea cols="10" rows="5"><?php echo $sql ?></textarea>
<textarea cols="10" rows="5"><?php echo $sql1 ?></textarea>
<textarea cols="10" rows="5">Jokes no3</textarea>
<textarea cols="10" rows="5">Jokes no4</textarea>
<textarea cols="10" rows="5">Jokes no5</textarea>
```

I have written like this. in this way i have to write 100 times if i have 100 jokes so there is any suite idea for me.. i am beginner so quite simple plz

Comment: [First step is to learn how to use MySQL with PHP by reading the manual.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php) Then if you have a problem come back as your code is not even a valid code.

Comment: You need to learn the basics of PHP and MySQL by finishing tutorials you started. Asking questions where people have to code for you isn't really going to help much, and if that's the code you use - it doesn't even work because it's not valid PHP. The idea behind learning things is that you sometimes come to conclusion yourself trough trial and error.

Answer (score 2):

```
$db = new PDO("database", "username", "password");
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT jokes FROM tbl_jk LIMIT 100");
$statement->execute();
foreach ($statement->fetchAll() as $joke) {
    echo '<textarea cols="10" rows="5">' . $joke['jokes'] . '</textarea>';
}
```

Place the above inside your php tags and replace the PDO inputs with your respective ones. The `LIMIT` can be taken away if you want all or only so many.

**EDIT:** More explination:

- `$db` creates a new connection to your specific database using the PHP PDO class.
- `prepare` records your initial query, a `SELECT` statement in this case, values can be placed in later (by `execute()`) using the `:variable` method.
- `execute()` can accept inputs to replace the `:variable` placeholders but will otherwise just execute the query you've previously prepared on the existing `$db` connection.
- `fetchAll()` will return all the rows that were retrieved from the previous `execute()` setting each one to the variable `$joke`.
  Your columns can then be accessed through `$joke['column_name']`

There are many types of `fetch()` in PDO, read up on PDO here: http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php

Comment: Also, try not to use mysql_query() it's depreciated. Note: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: Since there's a beginner in question here, you should expand your answer and describe what and why you did it that way. But if you just want to fish for reputation on "easy" questions - then I can assure you that you're wasting your time.

Comment: More explanation added.

Comment: @N.B. 
I dont care about reputation. Just want to know solution. I don't know  how do that so i asked. If i already know, there is no need to ask isn't it?

Comment: @EnticAshish - I wasn't referring to you, but to Sam. That's why I commented his answer.

Comment: @N.B.
sorry miss-understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Try to select all the jokes at once instead of creating a SQL statement for every joke. 
You can LIMIT you select for selecting only the first 5 of the table.
Or when you have a date field you can sort them ASC or DESC.

```
$sql = "SELECT jokes FROM tbl_jk LIMIT 0,5";
```

Then use a loop and put then into the textarea you want.

```
foreach ( $statement->fetchAll() as $jk){
    echo '<textarea cols="10" rows="5">'. $jk .'</textarea>';
}
```

Maybe because your new to PHP and SQL I can give you an example about the output:

```
$jokes = Array(
              '1' => 'Joke 1',
              '2' => 'Joke 2',
              '3' => 'Joke 3',
              '4' => 'Joke 4',
              '5' => 'Joke 5'
              );
    You should receive some array like this from you database, after that we loop over them all and we put them into the textarea. 

    foreach ( $jokes as $jk){
      echo '<textarea cols="10" rows="5">'. $jk .'</textarea><br />';
    }
```

Try to use PDO instead of mysql_query.
What does fetchAll do?

> **PDOStatement::fetchAll()** returns an array containing all of the
>   remaining rows in the result set. The array represents each row as
>   either an array of column values or an object with properties
>   corresponding to each column name. An empty array is returned if there
>   are zero results to fetch, or FALSE on failure.